# Amplify add storage - Auth configuration is required to allow unauthenticated users, but it is not configured properly

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm pretty sure I have cognito configured correctly because I can register, sign in, and sign out. Everything is configured in aws-exports. Anyone know how to debug this?

```
$ amplify add storage
? Please select from one of the below mentioned services: Content (Images, audio, video, etc.)
? Please provide a friendly name for your resource that will be used to label this category in the project: botshopsStorage
? Please provide bucket name: botshops
? Who should have access: Auth and guest users
? What kind of access do you want for Authenticated users? create/update, read, delete
? What kind of access do you want for Guest users? read
? Do you want to add a Lambda Trigger for your S3 Bucket? No
Auth configuration is required to allow unauthenticated users, but it is not configured properly.
An error occurred when adding the storage resource
Error: Auth configuration is required to allow unauthenticated users, but it is not configured properly.
    at configure (C:\snapshot\node_modules\amplify-category-storage\lib\provider-utils\awscloudformation\service-walkthroughs\s3-walkthrough.js:405:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async addWalkthrough (C:\snapshot\node_modules\amplify-category-storage\lib\provider-utils\awscloudformation\service-walkthroughs\s3-walkthrough.js:58:12)
    at async Object.executeAmplifyCommand (C:\snapshot\node_modules\amplify-category-storage\lib\index.js:114:3)
    at async executePluginModuleCommand (C:\snapshot\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\lib\execution-manager.js:163:5)
    at async Object.executeCommand (C:\snapshot\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\lib\execution-manager.js:35:9)
    at async Object.run (C:\snapshot\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\lib\index.js:112:9)

micha@DESKTOP-P5RTAG7 MINGW64 ~/repos/botshops (master)
$ amplify status

Current Environment: dev

| Category | Resource name    | Operation | Provider plugin   |
| -------- | ---------------- | --------- | ----------------- |
| Auth     | botshopsff8e5633 | No Change | awscloudformation |
| Api      | botshops         | No Change | awscloudformation |
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to say anything without seeing how you configured the unauthenticated role and whether unauthenticated access is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to remove the auth and add it back again.
amplify remove auth
amplify add auth